# How to change network that works on a subset of the input?

Tags: neural-networks, architecture

To clarify my question, I'll take an example: let's say you're trying to classify pictures, by determining whether there's a dog or not in the picture. Let's assume the pictures to be 1000x1000 pixels. Let's also assume that the dogs are always located in a specific region of the pictures, in the training/validation/test set and in the real world-data the network is going to encounter. The rest of the picture is irrelevant to the classification task.
I know that an easy thing to do would be to only select this region and train a neural network on the cropped dataset. But if you don't know where this region is or whether that region even exists, you're going to train a network on the full dataset.

So I have a few question: first of all, would a good neural network on the full dataset find by itself the region of interest and consider the other parts of the pictures as noise? And secondly, if there's a network that's capable of having a good accuracy on the cropped dataset, how would you change it to have good accuracy on the full dataset?

I have been working on a similar problem (though in 1 dimension and not 2), but I can't find a network that performs better than random chance on the full dataset, even though I have found a network that performs better than random chance on the cropped dataset. Is noise that much of a problem for a network?

Comment: CNN segmenters are asked to find any dogs in a picture so they certainly can determine the region of interest.  They're not my specialty but there is often a network which decides which segments of the picture have something of interest and a second which classifies it (what you describe as the network which operates on the cropped dataset).

Comment: A network may or may not have an issue with noise surrounding data of interest.  But one thing is sure, it will likely need many examples of surrounding noise to learn it is to be ignored.